# Example in TopCoder violates constraints

Tags: algorithm, combinations, dynamic-programming

I am trying to understand the question [DivFreed2](https://community.topcoder.com/stat?c=problem_statement&pm=14186) on TopCoder:

It specifically specifies that arrays

- The length of the array is n.
- Each element is an integer between 1 and k, inclusive.
- **Whenever A and B are two consecutive elements of the array (in this order), we have (A <= B) or (A mod B != 0).**

My problem is the third constraint with respect to the first example given:

```
2
2
Returns: 3
The three arrays Hero likes are {1,1}, {1,2}, and {2,2}.
```

**Shouldn't the answer be 4 ?  What happened to the array {2,1} ?** There are 3 arrays that can be generated following the mentioned constraints, but thre is also a fourth array that can be generated which is {2,1}. No where in the question is it written that we can only have unique combinations of the numbers. **Why aren't we including {2,1} in the list of arrays that can be valid ?**

All the questions specify is the constraint of the arrangement of the numbers.

**Am I missing something here ? Does an array of numbers mean the unique combination ?**

Comment: "Shouldn't the answer be 4" What does *4* mean? What does *answer* mean? Please explain those in your question, as the TC question may go away, but [so] questions are supposed to be timeless.

Comment: @jpaugh Check the edited question, and let me know if any further clarification is needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, `2 > 1`, and `2 % 1 == 0`, therefore

```
!(2 <= 1) && !(2 % 1 != 0)
```

therefore `{2, 1}` is not a solution.